# Azure/Office 365 Portal branding cuztomization

Tags: azure, office365

We created our Office 365 account back in March and subscribed for a trial of Windows Azure so we could try the "branding customization" feature for the Office 365 Portal / Outlook Web App as described on:
 http://www.office365tipoftheday.com/2013/12/17/customize-your-office-365-login-page/

We tested it with random pictures and forgot about it until today.

We are now starting to migrate users to Exchange Online and want those random pictures gone. Problem is, we no longer have access to that feature... Trial was expired so has to subscribe for the "Pay-as-you-go" plan; but we still have no way to remove the brandings.

We don't have any support for Azure and I doubt the Office 365 technical support can help.

What's our options? Will brandings go away on July 1st?

> *Users who are not properly licensed after July 1, 2014 will not be able to continue to use the incremental features offered by the Premium tier and service will downgrade to the Free tier.*
>   
> http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the custom branding feature for Office 365 you must sign into your Azure subscription and sign-up for Azure AD Premium features:

http://www.office365tipoftheday.com/2013/12/17/customize-your-office-365-login-page/

Which allows to achieve this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532270.aspx

If you aren't signed up for Azure AD Premium these features are not available.